# Formatting output for a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

The output looks like this

```
bbnum,building,floor,cluster,row,position,namespaces

BBEG,BUILDEG,1,CLUsEG,5,19,namespaceEG
```

I would like to add spaces throughout, match up the top row with the bottom and delete cluster, row and namespaces (Delete the top and bottom part of the provided list)

Im trying to make it look something like this. Just trying to make it look neat

```
bbnum  building  floor  row  position

BBEG   BUILDEG    1          5     19
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The output of what? You should be able to do what you want with `printf`, you can specify the width of each field in the format satring.

Comment: Almost but not quite.  `awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '{$NF = ""; $1=$1}1' file.txt`

Comment: Or ... `command_with_output | awk -F, -v OFS='\t' '{$NF = ""; $1=$1}1'`

Comment: Or `...| awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6}' FS=, OFS=\\t`

Answer (score 2):

Edit: <strike>remove comma with sed</strike> and try piping your output to `column -ts,` command like this:

```
$ echo -e "bbnum,building,floor,cluster,row,position,namespaces\nBBEG,BUILDEG,1,CLUsEG,5,19,namespaceEG" | column -ts,
bbnum  building  floor  cluster  row  position  namespaces
BBEG   BUILDEG   1      CLUsEG   5    19        namespaceEG
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @dreamchaser1024 Please have a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers>

Comment: @Quasímodo: there you go

Answer (score 0):

```
while read; do
  printf "%10s %10s %10s %10s\n" $(echo "$REPLY"|cut -d "," --output-delimiter " " -f 1-3,6)
done < yourfile.txt
```